# Add records to pivot table

Tags: laravel, pivot-table

i have 3 tables.

table users

```
id 
name
```

table identifiers

```
id 
email
```

and pivot table identifier_user

```
identifier_id
user_id
```

when store data I when to add data to the pivot table, example :

```
$user=new User ;
$iden=new Identifier ;
```

I use $user->identifiers()->attach($user->id) , but the one just add the data to `identifier_id` but i want to add data to `user_id` to

**NB**: I made the relationship ManeytoManey  in the two models

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you cannot do your task like in question, cause `$user = new User;` only creates default User class instance.

For example: if you doesn't have a user, you need to create it like this:

`$user = User::create($userData);`

But if you already has user in database:

`$user = User::findOrFail($userId);` or `$user = User::where(['some_field' => $some_value])->first();`

After that, you can attach relation:

`$user->identifiers()->attach([$identifier_ids]);`

if you already know relation ids, or, if you need to create it:

`$user->identifiers()->([
    new Identifier($identifierDataArray),
    new Identifier($identifierDataArray),
]);`

Hope it helps you.